# Running toast in at certain interval in a service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, handler

I am trying to show a toast at 2 seconds interval from a service.
This normal code works fine. This one is just a test to show toast.

```html
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        new Thread(new ToastRunner(this)).start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

But the below code crashes...

```html
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        new Thread(new ToastRunner(this)).start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    class ToastRunner implements Runnable{
        Context context;

        public ToastRunner(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("tag", e.toString() );
            }
        }
    }
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
while (true) {
       new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
```

Comment: I don't know why the negative rep. But this code works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Only problem is it keeps on running even after the service is destroyed.

Comment: then in the onDestroy() of your service interupt the thread.i,e,.
onDestroy(){ thead.interrupt(); }

Comment: ok fixed it using a variable boolean..
`
while (isRunning) {
       new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
`

Answer (score 0):

That mean you cannot access ui element from one another thread. You must use uiThred. Try this code,

```
           while (true) {
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                      }
                    }
           }
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this...

```
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    // preparing a looper on current thread    
    // the current thread is being detected implicitly
    Looper.prepare();


// now, the handler will automatically bind to the
// Looper that is attached to the current thread
// You don't need to specify the Looper explicitly
handler = new Handler();

// After the following line the thread will start
// running the message loop and will not normally
// exit the loop unless a problem happens or you
// quit() the looper (see below)
Looper.loop();


 } 
catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, "halted due to an error", t);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not very helpful to me. I need more elaboration.